# Travel within Europe with a single entry visa

Tags: visas, schengen, france, georgian-citizens

I am from Georgia and have a D category long-term Schengen visa but is marked 01 which means that it's a single entry. Am I able to go from Poland to France by plane?

I asked this question and I was given an answer that I can, but my friends with the same visa had a problem. They used it transit Spain en route to the UK, but they were refused entry at the UK border.

Can I travel or not? I have already the tickets to France and do not want to be refused entry.

Comment: While your friends could enter Spain with a Schengen visa, it does not allow entry to the UK; a UK visa is required for that.

Comment: The UK is not part of the Schengen area. It has its own immigration rules, visas, and border controls. So it's not surprising that your friends were refused entry there.

Comment: It was an transit flight and still needs a UK visa right? As I understand @dorothy

Comment: So the most important question is I can go to France, yes? @zachLipton

Comment: Yes; his Schengen visa allowed him enter into Spain and, without a UK visa, he should not have been allowed to board a flight to the UK. Your plan is to fly from Georgia to France. You will enter the Schengen Area once, when you arrive in France. When you leave the Schengen Area, you will not be able to use the same visa to go back, but would have to apply for a new visa.

Comment: No, I am a stundet in Poland now, I have already entered the schemgen atea and that means that I cant go from Poland to France? @Dorothy

Comment: @Janny You can go from Poland to France, see my answer

Comment: Of course you can; see @Crazydre answer and [study this](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/index_en.htm) to understand the Area :-)

Answer (score 14):

Both Poland and France are Schengen countries, so you are not leaving the Schengen Area by flying between them. In fact, there will be no border control - the flight is like a domestic flight.

When your friends went to the UK, they were refused entry because the UK is not a Schengen country, but an "independent country" with its own border and a separate visa policy. Thus, a Schengen visa is **not** valid for the UK.

If you went from Poland via a UK airport to France, you would exit the Schengen Area when leaving Poland, and would **not** be able to re-enter it in France.

However, if flying directly from Poland to France, you are not leaving Schengen, so you will have **no** problems

Comment: @Janny If this answers your question, please accept the answer by pressing the button below the down arrow